Are product names treated as singular or plural?
Are product names treated as singular or plural? Some names like, Nike All Court Basketball would be treated as singular. The Nike All Court Basketball lets you...
But what about names that end with an 's'? For example would it be
The Converse CTAS Tough Textures let...
OR
The Converse CTAS Tough Textures lets...

Does "Converse CTAS Tough Textures" refer to a single product or a range of products? If so "Converse CTAS Tough Texture" might be meaningful. For your sentence it may be better to use "The Converse CTAS Tough Textures surface lets ...".

The incorrectly claimed duplicate is about standardisation of spelling of plural forms ('Walkmen' or 'Walkmans'?), not about whether one should use Snickers is/are; Golden Grahams is/are. Of course, notional agreement has often been addressed before, though I haven't found a thread addressing product names as opposed to say books ('Sons and Lovers was banned ...') / place names ('The Trossachs is ...') / sports clubs ('The Yankees win' but 'New York wins' in the US; 'City/Rovers win the FA Cup' in the UK) ...

There's also the issue that some products have a plural form of the name on the packet: Kelloggs Corn Flakes, Choco Krispies/Coco Pops, Bran Flakes, Lucky Charms, Jumbo Oats; while others have a singular: Weetabix, Shredded Wheat, Bitesize Shredded Wheat. And some singular forms appear to be mass nouns: brands of Muesli and Granola, Special K, Jordan's Country Crisp. Even though some of the singulars  could be pluralised. Sometimes it's to do with item size or the number in a serving, sometimes it's not.

Would you say 'The Grapes of Wrath are a great book'?
Of course, 'Kellogs Corn Flakes is very tasty' sounds off.
I'd say treat each case on its merit.
Is it better to see and thus treat (adopting logical rather than formal agreement) 'The Converse CTAS Tough Textures' as a product or individual items?
One can find many examples using either singular or plural agreement, for instance:

SNICKERS is called the Marathon Bar in the UK. [Snickers]
This is how good Golden Grahams are. [Dan Bishop; critic]

Usages tend to become set, but with novel products, there is usually a free choice for the producers to specify.
But Thomas McKinlay, at Tips Anyhow.com, claims in the article 'Use a plural (vs singular) brand name'


People are up to 13.4% more likely to prefer a plural brand name (e.g.
Snickers), vs a singular one (e.g. Snicker) for a mainstream product.


This is relevant on ELU as it is an example of societal values affecting language, and doubtless language influencing societal values.
